# Can't match if statement where an ampersand is in the string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do an if statement:

```
if($('.subscription-type').html() == "Full Online & Print Access") {
        console.log("inside full");
        //if($('.subscription-type').html() == "Full Online & Print Access") {
```

and it never goes into the if statement. When I do a printout in the console of subscription-type, I get this:

```
Subscription type:Full Online & Print Access
```

It seems that the issue is the ampersand. How can I fix my code?

Comment: Double-check to make sure your ampersand isn't actually HTML entity-escaped as `&amp;`

Answer (score 5):

`&` is actually a special character in HTML. It marks the beginning of an [*HTML entity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction#Named_character_references). So to create a literal `&` you would have to use `&amp;` in HTML, and that's what `.html` will return.

To get the text without HTML entities (just as you see it), use `.text` instead of `.html`:

```
if($('.subscription-type').text() === "Full Online & Print Access") {
```

It might also be that you have leading and/or trailing whitespace characters. In that case you want to also apply [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) to the return value.